# <listRel:entityId>(.*?)<\/listRel:entityId>

Tags: regex, rubular

Good day.

My work requires me to query and get response from it. I cannot seem to remove the letters or name on this Match group. I need to get just the numbers 917857

I use rubular to check if the match is correct.

917857 James Bond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Regex to get the number where the number is at the start of the string and is only numbers:

```
\<listRel:entityId\>(\d+)[\s\w]+<\/listRel:entityId\>
```

Here is a working example:  [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gFGz4j/1)

This is adjusted to match the additional input example.

Comment: Thank you RudyTheHunter for your answer.
I'm actually getting a no match. 
http://rubular.com/r/FDodPBva96

Comment: This solved the issue. Thank you RTH. Will try to post a more informative question next time

Comment: Thanks, can you select my solution as the answer?